# HTML5, creating a left, right and top center category filter bar?

Tags: html, css, web

What iam trying to do is basically create a directory. I need a left sidebar to filter it by something, a right sidebar to filter it by something again and a top center bar to filter it by something again while the content will be in the middle.

Here is my html code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="eng"> 
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>My directory</title>
    <link rel ="stylesheet"href = "main.css">
</head> 
<body>
    <div id = "big_wrapper">
    <header id="top_header">
        <h1>My directory<h1>
    </header>

    <nav id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Ad enquiry</li>
        <ul>
    </nav>
    <aside id = "sidebar1" > <!--sidebar--> 

            <h2>Filter by Location</h1>
                <p>Suva</p>
                <p>Nadi</p>
                <p>Lautoka</p>              
    </aside>

    <section id="content"> <!--content-->

        <article> <!--similar information, own layout-->
            <header>
                <hgroup>
                    <h2>Aramco Construction</h1>
                <hgroup>
            </header>

            <p>Industry : Construction</p>
            <p>Location : Suva</p>
            <p>Link : N/A</p>           

            <footer>
            </footer>
        </article>

        <article> <!--similar information, own layout-->
            <header>
                <hgroup>
                    <h2>Classic Pools</h1>
                <hgroup>
            </header>

            <p>Industry : Construction</p>
            <p>Location : Suva</p>
            <p>Link : N/A</p>           

            <footer>
            </footer>
        </article>

    </section>

    <aside id = "leftbar" > <!--sidebar-->  

            <h2>Filter by xxxxx</h1>
                <p>lol</p>

    </aside>
    <aside id = "rightbar" > <!--sidebar--> 

            <h2>Filter by yyy</h2>
                <p>yolo</p> 


    </aside>
    <aside id = "topbar" > <!--sidebar-->   

            <h2>Filter by Alphabet</h2>
                <p>A</p>
                <p>B</p>
                <p>C</p>

    </aside>

    <footer id="footer_lol">
        Copyright Shuyaib 2014
    </footer>.
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

my css code

```
*{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;

}
h1{
    font: bold 20px Tahoma;
}
h2{
    font: bold 14px Tahoma;
}
header, section, footer, aside, nav, article, hgroup{
    display:block;
}

body{
    text-align:center;
    }

#big_wrapper
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width:1000px;
    margin:20px auto;
    text-align:left;
}
#top_header
{
    background:yellow;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding:20px;
}
#tabs
{
    background:blue;
    color:white;
}
#tabs li
{
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    padding: 5px;
    font: bold 14px Tahoma;

}
#leftbar
{
    float:left;
    width:150px;
    margin:20px 0px;
    padding:30px;
    background:blue;    
}
#rightbar
{
    float:right;
    width:150px;
    margin:750px 0px;
    padding:30px;
    background:blue;    
}
#topbar
{
    float:centre;
    width:500px;
    margin:20px 0px;
    padding:30px;
    background:blue;    
}
#content
{
    float: left;
    width:250px;
    margin-left:250px;
    margin-top:40px;
    background: red;

}


#footer_lol
{
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
    padding:20px;
    border-top:2px solid green;


}
```

the problem is, i want 150px for my left bar, 150 for my right bar and the remaining 700 px for my centre, howver the content comes on top of my left bar and so messing with it around i can't seem to align it correctly ? Any recommendations ?

Comment: If you don't need to worry about older browsers, try using flexbox - http://learnlayout.com/flexbox.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using hard coded values, why not try messing around with using percents?  I do believe your padding is also messing with the margins.  you could try width 120px and 30px padding.  Just some suggestions!